# Hello, My target is, when I hit the button "create checkbox" it will automatically create a checkbox with ID without using input type text

Tags: javascript, html

Newbie here. My target is i want to disregard the input type text and add checkbox with id by just clicking the button

```html
<html>
    <body>
        Enter a Value <input type="text" id="prod" autofocus />
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="bt" value="Create Checkbox" onclick="createChk(prod)" />
        </p>
    
        <p id="container"></p>
    </body>
    
    <script>
        var i = 1;      // COUNTER, FOR CHECKBOX ID.
    
        function createChk(obj) {
            if (obj.value !== '') {
    
                var chk = document.createElement('input');  // CREATE CHECK BOX.
                chk.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox', 'button');       // SPECIFY THE TYPE OF ELEMENT.
                chk.setAttribute('id', 'prodName' + i);     // SET UNIQUE ID.
                chk.setAttribute('value', obj.value);
                chk.setAttribute('name', 'products');
    
                var lbl = document.createElement('label');  // CREATE LABEL.
                lbl.setAttribute('for', 'prodName' + i);
    
           
    
                // APPEND THE NEWLY CREATED CHECKBOX AND LABEL TO THE <p> ELEMENT.
                container.appendChild(chk);
                container.appendChild(lbl);
    
                obj.value = '';
                document.getElementById(obj.id).focus();
    
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </html>
```

See the snippet here: https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/practice-ground/default.htm?pg=create_checkboxes_using_javascript1

Comment: hello and Welcome to SO. Please take your time to read the guidelines and edit your question. Use a code snippet to provide the code instead of an unformatted and unordered mess.

Comment: Hi  just trying to see that i understand the question
you want to add a checkbox, regardless if the text input got value or not ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the solutions by the way. :D

Comment: @tacoshy Yes. I will. Sorry and thank you for your suggestion. I'll do a great job in formatting my codes next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope i have understand your question correctly

this code will add a checkbox, regardless of the text input value

all was removed is the `if` statement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Checkbox Dynamically using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
    Enter a Value <input type="text" id="prod" autofocus />
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="bt" value="Create Checkbox" onclick="createChk(prod)" />
    </p>

    <p id="container"></p>
</body>

<script>
    var i = 1;      // COUNTER, FOR CHECKBOX ID.

    function createChk(obj) {
        
            var chk = document.createElement('input');  // CREATE CHECK BOX.
            chk.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');       // SPECIFY THE TYPE OF ELEMENT.
            chk.setAttribute('id', 'prodName' + i);     // SET UNIQUE ID.
            chk.setAttribute('value', obj.value);
            chk.setAttribute('name', 'products');

            var lbl = document.createElement('label');  // CREATE LABEL.
            lbl.setAttribute('for', 'prodName' + i);

            // CREATE A TEXT NODE AND APPEND IT TO THE LABEL.
            lbl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.value));

            // APPEND THE NEWLY CREATED CHECKBOX AND LABEL TO THE <p> ELEMENT.
            container.appendChild(chk);
            container.appendChild(lbl);

            obj.value = '';
            document.getElementById(obj.id).focus();

            i = i + 1;
        
    }
</script>
</html>
```